# Relating phase shift to the ROL/ROR operations

Tags: discrete-signals, continuous-signals, phase

Is phase-shifting in continuous-time analogous to the rotate-left (ROL) and rotate-right (ROR) operations in discrete-time?

Comment: When a signal is **delayed** or **advanced** in time, the result is a **phase shift** in the Frequency domain. That's true for both continuous time and also for discrete time systems. Note that for practical processing of discrete time signals the shifts are **circular**, that the relations must be interpreted that way when a shift is involved in respecive variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean phase shift of a sinusoid, then yes, a phase shift is equivalent to a translation.